# NestJs runtime injection

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, nestjs

I have scinario I implemented before in express app using inversifyjs, I need to implement it using nestjs.

I have services(A, B,C) that implement abstact class(Service Abstract) which inheret from the interface (IService). I need to inject one from above services (A or B or C) based on param in route (/:serviceType). How can I achieve that in nest ?

Comment: Probably a ‘factory’ provider that will return one of those services based on an arg (route param).

Comment: Do you mean using custom provider `useFactory`? or you mean I create a factory service that return instance of service based on param value. I can't find enough examples to apply `useFactory`. In inversify I can do it using factory in inversify config file.

Comment: These two options don't contradict each other. The way it would work depends on whether you need A, etc to be singletons or not.

Answer (score 2):

It can be function service defined with `useFactory` that returns A, B or else based on provided argument:

```
providers: [{
  provide: 'GET_AB',
  useFactory: (a: A, b: B) => {
    return (name) => {
     if (name === 'a')
       return a;
     else if (name === 'b')
       return b;
    };
  },
  inject: [A, B]
}]
```

Injected `GET_AB` is a function that is used like `aOrB = getAB('a')`;

Comment: Thanks @estus-flask for your response. Where to put this code in `app.module.ts` right or put it in seperate file and import it in `app.module.ts`?  and how can I inject it in service callead for example `product.service.ts` ? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: It's up to you but I don't see a reason to define it in separate file, it's not a reusable code, just put it inside `@Module(...)`. It's injected with `@Inject` this way https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#property-based-injection or this way https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#non-class-based-provider-tokens , as long as product.service belongs to a module that has this provider.

Comment: so the injection will be like that :
`@Inject('GET_AB') providerFactory : GetAB` , but `GetAB` it is undefined

Comment: and to call it `this.providerFactory('a')` , right ?

Comment: Yes, it's called like that. There's no GetAB and it's unnecessary to have it because dep type isn't used for DI with `@Inject`. You may want to declare factory function outside `providers` just for typing purposes, `export const getABFactory = (a: A, b: B) => ...`, and then it'll be `@Inject('GET_AB') providerFactory : ReturnType<typeof getABFactory>`

Comment: here is my constructor now 
`constructor(@Inject('GET_AB') providerFactory){
        this.factoryProvider = providerFactory
    }`

and I called it within a method `const providerService :ChannelsAbstract= this.factoryProvider('tyntec')` 
when I call function called findX from channelsAbstract like this `providerService.findX()` I got error that findX is not a function

Comment: This depends on your implementation details. Debug what providerService is in your case. Also it won't work if `A`, etc aren't class providers in current injector.